# ¿Por que los datos no se visualizan correctamente al usar INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, ni RIGHT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, sql

Tengo un error en mi consulta que aun no se como resolver, verán estoy tratando de hacer una tabla con la información referente a los usuarios del sistema,  el problema es el siguiente:

Procedí a probar la siguiente consulta MYSQL en la pestaña de código MYSQL de phpmyadmin.

```
SELECT u.ced_usu, u.nom_usu, n.nivel 
FROM usuarios u 
LEFT JOIN nivel_usuario n  ON u.id_niv = n.nivel
```

Si utilizo el `LEFT JOIN` no devuelve ningún mensajes de error, sin embargo a la hora observar los datos llamados me encuentro con que únicamente se muestran los datos de solo una de las tablas.

[image]

Como pueden ver algunos de los datos se muestran como nulos, específicamente los que provienen de una tabla diferente.
 En caso de usar otra opción como el  `RIGHT JOIN` lo único que consigo es invertir el resultado

[image]

Esos dos fueron los mejores resultados que conseguí ya que si utilizo un `INNER JOIN` directamente me devolverá los campos completamente vacíos:[image]

La verdad no entiendo a que se puede deber este tipo de errores, el campo nivel pertenece a una tabla llamada nivel_usuario pero esta esta correctamente relacionada a la tabla usuarios en la que se encuentran los otros dos campos.

Apreciaría cualquier tipo de concejo o ayuda ya que la verdad soy bastante nuevo en este tipo de cosas

Comment: `nivel_usuario.nivel` es tipo VARCHAR, ¿Qué tipo es `usuarios.id_nivel`?

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es que no tienes ningún error.
Si realizas la consulta

```
SELECT u.ced_usu, u.nom_usu, u.id_niv  
FROM usuarios u
```

verás que los `id_niv` de la tabla `usuarios` no tienen relación con los existentes en el campo `nivel` de la tabla `nivel_usuario`.